# if_all and if_any functions in dplyr are not running

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to replicate these examples using the `if_all` and `if_any` functions but its not working.

```
Erro: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x não foi possível encontrar a função "if_all"
i Input `..1` is `if_all(contains("bill"), big)`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/02/dplyr-1-0-4-if-any/

Why?

Comment: looks like you don't have the latest version of `dplyr`. Run `install.packages("dplyr")` and go through the full example from the beginning and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Did you run the following first before executing your code?

```r
## THIS STUFF

# Ensure you are running the latest version of dplyr:
install.packages("dplyr")

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(palmerpenguins)

big <- function(x) {
  x > mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
}

# THEN THIS STUFF

penguins %>% 
  filter(if_all(contains("bill"), big))
```

If that doesn't work, please update your question to include the output from `sessionInfo()`.